# Laravel Form validation is not working during Form Updation

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In my laravel project am using js validator, but during form updation , Validation is not working. My form is not submitting, if I did not made any changes. Sometimes it shows error to the email field.

Following is my validation code,

```
protected $edituserValidationRules = [
        'user_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
    ];
```

Following is the code to pass validation and other things to view

```
public function viewUsers($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);

        $validator = JsValidator::make($this->edituserValidationRules,[],[],'#useredit');
        return view('user.update')->with(['validator' => $validator,'users'=> $users]);

    }
```

Following is the code to update that particular user

```
public function updateUsers(Request $request , $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users' . $request->id
        ]);

        $postdata = $request->all();
        $user = new User;
        $user = User::find($id);
        $hashedRandomPassword = Hash::make($postdata['password'], [
            'rounds' => 12
        ]);
        $api_key = Str::random(16);
        $checkApiKey = User::where('api_key', $api_key)->first();
        if(!empty($checkApiKey)) {
            $api_key = Str::random(16);
        }
       $user = new User;
       $user->name=$postdata['user_name'];
       $user->email=$postdata['email'];
       $user->password= $hashedRandomPassword;
       $user->ip_address=$request->ip();
       $user->api_key=$api_key;
        if($user->save()){
            Session::flash('message', 'User Updated Sucessfully');
            Session::flash('msgclass', 'alert-success');
        }
        return redirect('users');

    }
```

Following is the code in view page

```
@extends('user.layout.app')

@section('content')
    <script src="{{ url('js/user/location.js') }}"></script>
    <div class="container-fluid add-location">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <form method="post" action="{!! route('updateUsers', [$users->id]); !!}" name="useredit" id="useredit" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <h4 class="card-title"> Edit User </h4>
                        </div>
                        @if(!empty($errors->all()))
                            <div class="row"> @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger"> <span>{{ $error }}</span> </div>
                                    </div>
                                @endforeach </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">Full Name
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input id="user_name" name="user_name" class="controls form-control" type="text" placeholder="User Name" value="{{$users->name}}">
                                        @if ($errors->has('user_name')) <span class="help-block"> {{ $errors->first('user_name') }} </span> @endif </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{$users->email}}" placeholder="Email">
                                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="password" class="control-label">Password
                                            <star>*</star>
                                        </label>
                                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="{{bcrypt($users->password)}}">
                                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                            <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                        @endif
                                    </div>

                                </div> -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">


                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 form-action">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-fill btn-info">Submit</button>
                                        <a href="" class="btn btn-default btn-fill">Cancel</a> </div>
                                </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {!! $validator !!}
@endsection
```

What is the problem here, during adding customers, I am checking for email already exists, same is checking here also.

I don't know what is happening? Please help

Comment: Write actual issue and make it clear.

Comment: @AlexandrBiship The issue, was form is not validating during updation. For example i just clicked on edit button and havent updated any values form is not submitting or it is giving dulpilcate entry error

Answer (score 0):

try changing this line

```
$this->validate($request, [
   'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users' . $request->id
]);
```

to

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$id
]);
```

Comment: I thnk its a problem with my update function , because while adding users , i have another form named password , but during updation am not allowing users to update the password

Comment: so tell me what is issue now ? is not updating or its not showing wrong message or what ?

Comment: While updating am getting error email id duplication, if i didnt change the email

Comment: check my answer , pass `$id` cause from your form you not passing id i guess

Comment: I am passing id

Comment: in your form i can't see any input filed with name id ? so how you are passing ?

Comment: In my public function updateUsers(Request $request , $id)  : $id is there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209136/discussion-between-xavier-issac-and-hamelraj).

Answer (score 0):

Adding **',id'** end of the statement which is used to prevent email exist check for the current id...

```
$request->validate([
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$request->id.',id',
]);
```